# Deck.GL TerrainLayer renders over other HTML elements

Tags: reactjs, deck.gl

When coding in DeckGL + React, the Terrain Layer Tiles render on top of all other HTML elements, regardless of the order specified in the DOM.

In this example I'd like to be able to render the `<Graph>` component on top of the Terrain Tiles in `<DeckGLMap>`

*the example has been edited for brevity

```
import './App.css';
import './styles.css';
import React from 'react'
import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';
import {TerrainLayer} from '@deck.gl/geo-layers';
import {GeoJsonLayer} from '@deck.gl/layers';
  
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  state = {
    focal_pt: "TEST",
    upstream: [],
    downstream: []
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Graph focal_pt={this.state.focal_pt}/>
        <div className="map-container">
          <DeckGLMap/>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}


class Graph extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

    render () {
      return <div className="graph">{this.props.focal_pt ? this.props.focal_pt.lat: ''}</div>
    }
}

class DeckGLMap extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  baseTerrain = new TerrainLayer({
    id: 'terrain',
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 18,
    pickable: true,
    // onClick: (info, event) => console.log('Clicked:', info.coordinate),
    onClick: (info, event) => {
      this.props.newFoci({lon: info.coordinate[0], lat: info.coordinate[1]})
    },
    strategy: 'no-overlap',
    elevationDecoder: ELEVATION_DECODER,
    elevationData: TERRAIN_IMAGE,
    texture: SURFACE_IMAGE,
    meshMaxError: 2.0,
    wireframe: false,
    color: [0, 0, 0]
  })

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="map">
        <DeckGL 
              initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE} 
              controller={true} 
              layers={[this.baseTerrain]}
      />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Wrapper />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've tried multiple hierarchies/orderings of the elements in the vDOM.  Is there a way to ensure that the tiles load with the intended ordering?

Comment: Can you include Codepen/CodeSandbox links?

Comment: Thanks @AdriSolid, I found an answer but will post a CodePen next time.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer in this post:
[Rendering NavigationControl with deck.gl](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/issues/662)

TL;DR:  set `style={{zIndex: '1'}}` on any `<divs>` that you'd like to render above DeckGL.  Applicable to other layers, not just TerrainLayer.